# How to read lines of numbers through string? (inside a loop)

Tags: php

I got help from a group user with the previous question, but instead of reading the lines from a txt file, i want to read the lines of numbers from a string.

1 and until 119

How can this be done?

Through txt file it works:

```
$lines = file("lines.txt");
if($i==119)
...
```

through string does not.

```
$numbers = "1
2
4
5
..."

for($i = 119; $i >= 0; $i--)
{   
$lines = "$numbers";
if($i==119)
{
$no_of_lines = round(count($lines)/14); 
}           

$line = $lines["$i"];
echo "$line<br>";

if( $i % 14 === 0 )
{       
echo "$no_of_lines<br>";
$no_of_lines--;
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) by `"\n"`? That should give you an array to work with

Answer (score 0):

To access your string you either need to know the position in the string where you could use substr but when your numbers get to 10 and beyond the length of 1 digit you can't know the position of each number.

So you could use explode to create an array called $lines delimited by a space (if all your numbers are separated by a space:-

$lines= explode(" ", $numbers);

so then your code could be :-

```
   <?php

$numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 6";

$lines= explode(" ", $numbers);

for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    $line = $lines[$i];
    echo "$line<br>";
}    

echo "<br>No_of_lines = " . count($lines);

?>
```

Which gives as your output :-

1
2
3
4
5
6

No_of_lines = 6